# qsynth not working with Jack on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, audio, jackd

I am trying to get qsynth to work on Ubuntu 22.04 (on a brand new computer).  It always fails saying "Qsynth1: Failed to create the audio driver (jack)."

I am running

```
Qsynth - A fluidsynth Qt GUI Interface
Version: 0.9.6
Using: Qt 5.15.3, FluidSynth 2.2.5
```

Jackd is

```
# jackd --version
jackdmp version 1.9.20 tmpdir /dev/shm protocol 9
```

Here is the error message:

```
16:38:16.257 Qsynth1: Creating synthesizer engine...
16:38:16.260 Qsynth1: Creating audio driver (jack)...
16:38:22.285 Qsynth1: Failed to create the audio driver (jack). Cannot continue without it.
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
Cannot create RT messagebuffer thread: Operation not permitted (1)
Retrying messagebuffer thread without RT scheduling
Messagebuffer not realtime; consider enabling RT scheduling for user
no message buffer overruns
Cannot create RT messagebuffer thread: Operation not permitted (1)
Retrying messagebuffer thread without RT scheduling
Messagebuffer not realtime; consider enabling RT scheduling for user
no message buffer overruns
Cannot create RT messagebuffer thread: Operation not permitted (1)
Retrying messagebuffer thread without RT scheduling
Messagebuffer not realtime; consider enabling RT scheduling for user
no message buffer overruns
jackdmp 1.9.20
Copyright 2001-2005 Paul Davis and others.
Copyright 2004-2016 Grame.
Copyright 2016-2021 Filipe Coelho.
jackdmp comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions; see the file COPYING for details
JACK server starting in realtime mode with priority 10
self-connect-mode is "Don't restrict self connect requests"
audio_reservation_init
Acquire audio card Audio0
creating alsa driver ... hw:0|hw:0|1024|2|48000|0|0|nomon|swmeter|-|32bit
ALSA: Cannot open PCM device alsa_pcm for playback. Falling back to capture-only mode
JackTemporaryException : now quits...
Released audio card Audio0
audio_reservation_finish
Cannot initialize driver
JackServer::Open failed with -1
Failed to open server
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
fluidsynth: error: Failed to connect to Jack server.
16:38:25.008 Qsynth1: Destroying synthesizer engine...
16:38:25.008 Qsynth1: Synthesizer engine terminated.
```

I have Googled the error and tried a lot of things but still no joy.